# Which javascript package has these alerts with a green checkmark

Tags: javascript, laravel, notifications

I just wanted to know which javasript plugin or package has these notifications after a successfull operation is done....i've seen it on Laracasts and on this video:

https://youtu.be/QqULa0PIaGU?t=290

[image]

Comment: That would be [sweet alert 2](https://limonte.github.io/sweetalert2/).

Comment: Thank you very much...you can put it in Answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this man https://limonte.github.io/sweetalert2/ very cool plugin for do this

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please [add context around the link](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8259/169503) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. Take into account that being _barely more than a link to an external site_ is a possible reason as to [Why and how are some answers deleted?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).